# What's the difference between "Bag of Words" and "Bag of features" in computer vision?

Tags: feature-selection, bag

Researching the subject, one can find papers where the author makes **image** classification / retrieval using the "Bag of Words" model, while others do similar tasks using a "Bag of features" model.

Even though I have a basic understanding of the method involved (detect and extract visual words, build a visual dictionary, use machine learning to train a classifier), I still can't see the difference between both models. Are they synonyms? Maybe I have missed concrete examples / documentation that shows the difference...

Answer (score 7):

At first there was the **Bag of Words** model for **document** retrieval. This model considered every document (and the query too) to be a bag of words (without taking the position of each word into account). So every document was transformed into a vector of the size of the language dictionary keeping the frequency of each term (histogram)

The **Bag of Visual Words** or **Bag of Features** replace the document with an image and the words with features (or "Visual Words") and create a very similar representation of an image. So yes the BoF is synonym of the BoVW. The BoW is about text retrieval.