# Bag of visual word model for feature clustering

Tags: opencv, histogram, sift, feature-extraction

I am using bag of visual words to cluster the features of the image. So far all the work i came across used BOW for clustering features computed using SIFT, SURF, etc. Maybe I missed this out but is it possible to represent Color Histogram Feature into BOW and also Edge oriented Histogram feature in BOW.

I am working on image classifier and I want to used SIFT with RGB color Histogram as feature descriptors in Opencv. So i was wondering is it correct to concatenate the 2 feature vectors into one and add to BOW or is it correct to add SIFT feature to BOW and concatenate the Histogram feature to BOW (I am using this model as of now but I am wondering which one is correct.)

Comment: You can use color-SIFT. Does that work for you?

Comment: Actually, it will work well but I my confusion is concatenation of 2 feature vector into BOW.

Answer (score 0):

Historically we use bag-of-words model for document retrieval. 
As mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192607/whats-the-difference-between-bag-of-words-and-bag-of-features-in-computer-v), in computer vision bag-of-visual-words refers to bag-of-features (BOF). If you want to use two types of features, you can concatenate the two feature vectors and build the BOF model. (As an example,) For human action recognition task people often models human action using BOF built on the concatenation of appearance feature (Gradient -- HOG) and motion feature (Optical Flow -- HOF).